# Layout.jade file opens but index.jade does not work in heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have deployed a node.js app on heroku where the layout.jade file works correctly but the index.jade fle opens in the default text of expess and not the file created by me.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have written in both files?

Comment: the code works appropriately on local server but is not giving correct output on heroku